# Best way to use Git repository as an AWS Lambda source within Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform

I'm working with Terraform to configure an AWS Lambda with API Gateway and DynamoDB,
for the infrastructure i'm using a private repository and for the Lambda code source i'm using a different private repository.

After a research i have already found a way to download a source code to use in Terraform using:

```
locals {
  package_url = "https://github.com/.../main.zip"
  downloaded  = "downloaded_package_${md5(local.package_url)}.zip"
  lambda_src_path = "${path.module}/lambda"

 }

resource "null_resource" "download_package" {
     triggers = {
          downloaded = local.downloaded
     }

     provisioner "local-exec" {
         command = "curl -L -o ${local.downloaded} ${local.package_url}"
     }
 }
```

This would work fine if the repo is public, otherwise a solution would be using:

```
curl -H 'Authorization: token TOKEN' \
-H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw' \
-O \
-L https://api.github.com/repos/owner/repo/contents/path
```

I would like to ask what would be the best solution to achieve that, maybe using .env data inside the Terraform repository.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Don't store secrets in .env file, since those would be part of repo and at risk to be compromised. You should never store secrets in repo.
The solution depends on where you actually have your repo hosted. But all providers support storing secrets one way or another.

For example github has https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets

Comment: yes i already use github secrets, but how can i used in Terrafrom ? and is it the best way to download the github repo within Terraform ?

Comment: Those secrets can be exposed as env variables in the pipeline, its well defined in documentation I sent you https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets#accessing-your-secrets

About the repo in terraform. You need to clone it in your case. But honestly it's pretty weird flow, I don't get it why you would use separate repo for storing Lambda code

Comment: as i said, i want to seperate  the infrastructure and the code, so i have already a pipline in the lambda repo to depoy it on push, and using terraform i am handling all the the infra in seperate repo

Comment: I just want a way so my terrafrom could create the lambda function from github repo nit from my local

Comment: So you have to clone the repo. 

But still I think you're doing it wrong, you're adding a lot of unnecessary complexity. Keeping infra in separate repo makes sense (VPC, Security Groups, S3 etc.). But terraform responsible for deployment of lambda would be better in same repo as code.

Comment: Exactly, now we are in the same page!

I agree with you @karjan but the catch now: What if i want to put my lambda function inside an other host (Github) and use there a CI/CD to deploy the function, which i already created, what would be the best way to do that ?

Comment: If I got you right, include Terraform responsible for deployment of Lambda in the same repo on that other host. 

So you have 2 separate workspaces, with separate states. 

Also if I may suggest it's pretty cumbersome to manage lambda functions with Terraform. My favorite is Serverless Framework, Amplify and SAM are also fine.

Comment: Thank you for your time & help and answer :D i ll go for Serverless Framework